# How can I refresh the activity?

Tags: android

I want to refresh the activity as i want thatwithout firing any event some work gets performed and activity calls  by itself. So, i want to know is there any option in android to refresh the activity by itself.

Comment: If you are using BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter simply call notifyDataSetChanged() to update your view

Comment: @100rabh : right. if he is refreshing a list. he should write, what and how he is actually trying to refresh. than we could give better information.

Comment: well i am trying to refresh whole activity

Comment: Chk this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134832/auto-refresh-the-activity/6840666#6840666

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by yourself through a Handler on which you call postDelayed(..)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)

Put this in your class:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
```

make a function called: doTheAutoRefresh() that does:

```
private void doTheAutoRefresh() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 doRefreshingStuff(); // this is where you put your refresh code
                 doTheAutoRefresh();                
             }
         }, 1000);
}
```

Call this function in your onCreate.

NOTE: this is the basic approach. consider stopping this after onPause has been called and to resume it after onResume. Look at the handler class to see how to remove.

Comment: autoRefresh() is predefined method or something else

Comment: well.. then just replace all the autoRefresh() above with doTheAutoRefresh()

Comment: I mean to say that is autoRefresh() is predefined or i have to define it

Comment: you have to define that function. let me edit above, so it is clear

Comment: this code doesn't work. is says add unimplemented functions and want to implement run.

Comment: sorry.. my code was written by hand and i forgot some small part. was more meant as an example than copy paste. but now it should work with copy paste (i hope) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a thread and and call the refresh() with the task you want to refresh

Answer (score -1):

for other questions I've pulled the most effective ways to do this are:

```
finish();startActivity(getIntent());
```

OR

```
// Refresh main activity upon close of dialog box
Intent refresh =new Intent(this, ActivityWeAreIn.class);
startActivity(refresh);
```

Note: this also works with Activity objects or from Fragments using getActivity()